# 多重プロジェクトの削除

Tags: monaca

monacaで3つのプロジェクトを作成　　いらないものを削除するにはどうしたらよいですか？

Answer (score 0):

プロジェクトを選択する場面で、アイコン（サムネイル）の左に小さいチェックボックスがあります。削除したいプロジェクトを選択すると、情報に削除ボタンが出現します。